# Apache module command parser prototype

Tags: c++, c, linux, apache, apache-modules

I am creating an Apache2 module and experiencing a weird compilation problem.
This is prototype of my function used to parse config command named "*analytics_ip*":

```
static const char *apr_cfg_set_analytics_ip(cmd_parms *cmd, void *config, const char *data);
```

This is array of *command_rec* structures containing pointers to this function:

```
static const command_rec apr_cmds[] =
{
 AP_INIT_TAKE1("analytics_ip", apr_cfg_set_analytics_ip, NULL, OR_ALL, ""),
 { NULL }
};
```

Structure command_rec is declared in header file *http_config.h*

```
typedef struct command_struct command_rec;
struct command_struct {
    /** Name of this command */
    const char *name;
    /** The function to be called when this directive is parsed */
    cmd_func func;
    /** Extra data, for functions which implement multiple commands... */
    void *cmd_data;
    /** What overrides need to be allowed to enable this command. */
    int req_override;
    /** What the command expects as arguments */
    enum cmd_how args_how;

    /** 'usage' message, in case of syntax errors */
    const char *errmsg;
};
```

When I follow *cmd_func*, it gets to the following declaration:

```
typedef const char *(*cmd_func) ();
```

If I am not mistaken, this means "pointer to function returning pointer to char and not accepting any arguments". How can this be possible? Command parsing function has to accept at least one parameter containing a module value of config variable corresponding to that function.

I am using g++ to compile this module.
Error message:

```
mod_xxx.h:65:2: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char* (*)(cmd_parms*, void*, const char*) {aka const char* (*)(cmd_parms_struct*, void*, const char*)}’ to ‘cmd_func {aka const char* (*)()}’ [-fpermissive]
  };
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cmd_func` is a union, it is defined in [http_config.h](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/2.4.x/include/http_config.h) as follows:

```
typedef union {
    /** function to call for a no-args */
    const char *(*no_args) (cmd_parms *parms, void *mconfig);
    /** function to call for a raw-args */
    const char *(*raw_args) (cmd_parms *parms, void *mconfig,
                             const char *args);
    /** function to call for a argv/argc */
    const char *(*take_argv) (cmd_parms *parms, void *mconfig,
                             int argc, char *const argv[]);
    /** function to call for a take1 */
    const char *(*take1) (cmd_parms *parms, void *mconfig, const char *w);
    /** function to call for a take2 */
    const char *(*take2) (cmd_parms *parms, void *mconfig, const char *w,
                          const char *w2);
    /** function to call for a take3 */
    const char *(*take3) (cmd_parms *parms, void *mconfig, const char *w,
                          const char *w2, const char *w3);
    /** function to call for a flag */
    const char *(*flag) (cmd_parms *parms, void *mconfig, int on);
} cmd_func;
```

`enum cmd_how args_how;` is responsible for choosing the correct version of the function.

The switch handling it is located in [server/config.c](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/2.4.x/server/config.c) (in the `invoke_cmd` function).

You seem to be using the "take1" version which corresponds to `cmd->AP_TAKE1` or simply `cmd->take1`.

The problem might be that C and C++ have [differences regarding the union initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555702/union-initialization-in-c-and-c). (`AP_INIT_TAKE1` uses the `{ .take1=func }` syntax which doesn't work in C++).

You'll have to initialize `static const command_rec apr_cmds` in a C++-compatible way or move it to a separate object file compiled with C. Or if you're not using C++ then simply compile with `gcc`.

Comment: I solved problem by hacking http_config.h

#ifdef __cplusplus
typedef const char *(*cmd_func) (cmd_parms *cmd, void *dummy, const char *path);
#else
typedef const char *(*cmd_func) ();
#endif

Comment: Oh, so close!  I'm having more success with ...
 #ifdef __cplusplus 
  typedef const char *(*cmd_func) (cmd_parms *cmd, void *dummy, ...); 
 #else 
  typedef const char *(*cmd_func) (); 
 #endif

Answer (score 1):

For the project I'm working on we ended up adding a cast to allow the compilation to complete successfully, and the code seems to work OK as it correctly reads in the values specified in the configuration file. Here's the extract of this practice:

`extern "C" {
    static const command_rec        kiwix_settings[] =
    {
        AP_INIT_TAKE1("zimFile", (const char* (*)())kiwix_set_zimfilename, NULL, RSRC_CONF, "The ZIM filename in full including the extension"),
        AP_INIT_TAKE1("zimPath", (const char* (*)())kiwix_set_path, NULL, RSRC_CONF, "The path to the ZIM file, including the trailing //"),
        { NULL }
    };
}`

The full file (and indeed the project) are opensourced. Here's the link to the full file https://github.com/kiwix/kiwix-apache/blob/master/mod_kiwix.cpp

PS: thanks for your question and https://stackoverflow.com/users/257568/artemgr's answer as they helped me and another volunteer to work out how to resolve the problem for our project.